# Quick question on an example of bad probability theory.

Tags: limits, probability-theory

From the text *Probability with martingales* by Williams.

[image]

I don't understand why $p(C_n) = 0$, is it not

$$P(C_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \# \{ k : 1 \le k \le n ; k \in C_n  \} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{\# \{ k : 1 \le k \le 1 ; k \in C_1  \}, \# \{ k : 1 \le k \le 2 ; k \in C_2  \}, \dots , \# \{ k : 1 \le k \le 2 ; k \in C_n  \} \}  = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{1, 2,  \dots, n \} = \infty $$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The $n$ in $C_n$ and the $n$ in the definition of $\rho$ are not the same. In other words $\rho(C_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\#\{k: 1\leq k\leq N; k\in C_n\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in the definition, it should surely be $\rho(C) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \# \{k \mid 1 \le k \le n, k \in C\}$.

You use the index $n$ twice, when you should actually use two different indices.

$$\rho(C_n) = \lim \limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{m}\#\{k \mid 1 \le k \le m, k \in C_n\}$$

Now note that
$$\frac{1}{m}\#\{k \mid 1 \le k \le m, k \in C_n\} = \begin{cases} 1 & m \le n \\ \frac{n}{m} & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$

**Edit:** It's not easy to find sets $F, G \in C$ that satisfy $F \cap G \notin C$. I don't have an explicit construction, but this should work:

Set $a_n = n^2 + n$, then $a_{n + 1} - a_n = 2n + 2$. Now choose for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ exactly $n + 1$ numbers from $(a_n, a_{n + 1}] \cap \mathbb{N}$ and combine them into a set $M$. This guarantess that $\frac{1}{a_n} \# (M \cap \{1, \ldots, a_n\}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and for $a_n < k < a_{n + 1}$ we can estimate:
$$\frac{1}{k} \#(C \cap \{1, \ldots, k\}) \le \frac{1}{a_{n}} \#(M \cap \{1, \ldots, a_{n + 1}\}) = \frac{a_{n + 1}}{2a_n}.$$

Since $\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} \to 1$, this implies $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \#(M \cap \{1, \ldots, n\}) \le \frac{1}{2}$. In a similar fashion the lower bound for the liminf is also $\frac{1}{2}$.

This means that every set we construct in this way has measure $\frac{1}{2}$ and therefore lies in $C$. Now we will construct our first set $F$ by selecting the numbers from $(a_n, a_{n + 1}] \cap \mathbb{N}$ to be $a_n + 1, a_n + 2, \ldots, a_n + n + 1$. For the set $G$ we will either

**(A)** Choose $a_n + 1, a_n + 2, \ldots, a_n + n + 1$
**(B)** Choose $a_n + n + 2, a_n + n + 3, \ldots, a_n + 2n + 2$

The decision of taking (A) or (B) will be done in the following way:

- Start chosing (A) until you've reached an $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{1}{a_{n_1}} \#(G \cap \{1, \ldots, a_{n_1}\}) \ge \frac{2}{5}$.
- Then you choose (B) until you've reached an $n_2 > n_1$ so that $\frac{1}{a_{n_2}} \#(G \cap \{1, \ldots, a_{n_2}\}) \le \frac{1}{5}$.
- Then you choose (A) until you've reached an $n_3 > n_2$ so that $\frac{1}{a_{n_3}} \#(G \cap \{1, \ldots, a_{n_3}\}) \ge \frac{2}{5}$.
- etc.

Comment: Could you even give me a hint as to finding two elements $F, G \in C$ s.t. $F \cap G \not \in C$ ?

Comment: Can I choose the sets such that they have an infinite amount of elements? I can't seem to find these two elements $F,G \in C$...

Comment: The sets actually need to have infinitely many elements [more specifically: their "measure" can be neither $0$ nor $1$]. I couldn't come up with an easy example, but the construction in the edit to my post should work.

Comment: Dominik: Simpler to write down but using the same idea: $F=2\mathbb N$ and $G$ made of the even numbers between $4^n$ and $2\cdot4^n$ for some integer $n$ and of the odd numbers between $2\cdot4^n$ and $4^{n+1}$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: @Did Nice example, this is definitely easier than my construction!

Comment: why is $\frac{1}{a_n} \# (M \cap \{1, \ldots, a_n\}) = \frac{1}{2}$? From your construction I get  $ \# (M \cap \{1, \ldots, a_n\})  = n(n+1) = a_n$. Also thank you very much and @did too.

Comment: This would mean $M = \mathbb{N}$, which is not the case. Note that always half the numbers between $a_n$ and $a_{n + 1}$ are chosen.